# MPI4PY OverflowError: integer 2333441511 does not fit in 'int'

Tags: python, mpi4py

I scatter list of nested dict without any number bigger than 200000, all the size of which are about 500M.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 220, in <module>
    recv = comm.scatter(send, root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1286, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.scatter (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:109079)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 707, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_scatter (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:48114)
  File "MPI/msgpickle.pxi", line 168, in mpi4py.MPI.Pickle.dumpv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:41672)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 35, in mpi4py.MPI.downcast (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:29070)
OverflowError: integer 2333441511 does not fit in 'int'
```

Comment: The exact cause is hard to say without the data, but basically it tried to pass a Python integer larger than 2³¹ to a C int, will cause an overflow. You have to make sure to filter out such values of change the type in the C lib, it that is possible.

Comment: It works after scanning all data. Thanks